# How to decode an Opaque data which has obtained by pysnmp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, snmp, pysnmp

I'm going to read data from an SNMP device by its OID via `pysnmp` library. However, I'm dealing with an error from Opaque type:

```py
from pysnmp import hlapi

def construct_object_types(list_of_oids):
    object_types = []
    for oid in list_of_oids:
        object_types.append(hlapi.ObjectType(hlapi.ObjectIdentity(oid)))
    return object_types

def get(target, oids, credentials, port=161, engine=hlapi.SnmpEngine(),
        context=hlapi.ContextData()):
    handler = hlapi.getCmd(
        engine,
        credentials,
        hlapi.UdpTransportTarget((target, port)),
        context,
        *construct_object_types(oids)
    )
    return fetch(handler, 1)[0]

def cast(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        try:
            return float(value)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            try:
                return str(value)
            except (ValueError, TypeError) as exc:
                print(exc)
    return value

def fetch(handler, count):
    result = []
    for i in range(count):
        (error_indication, error_status,
         error_index, var_binds) = next(handler)
        if not error_indication and not error_status:
            items = {}
            print(var_binds)
            for var_bind in var_binds:
                items[str(var_bind[0])] = cast(var_bind[1])
            result.append(items)
        else:
            raise RuntimeError(f'SNMP error: {error_indication}')
    return result


print(get("192.168.100.112", [".1.3.6.1.4.1.9839.1.2.532.0",
                              '.1.3.6.1.4.1.9839.1.2.513.0'],
          hlapi.CommunityData('public')))
```

Out:

```
[ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(<ObjectName value object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:6>, payload [1.3.6.1.4.1.9839.1.2.532.0]>), <Opaque value object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 64:0:4>, encoding iso-8859-1, payload [0x9f780441ccb646]>), ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(<ObjectName value object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:6>, payload [1.3.6.1.4.1.9839.1.2.513.0]>), <Integer value object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:2>, subtypeSpec <ConstraintsIntersection object, consts <ValueRangeConstraint object, consts -2147483648, 2147483647>>, payload [10]>)]
{'1.3.6.1.4.1.9839.1.2.532.0': '\x9fx\x04AÌ¶F', '1.3.6.1.4.1.9839.1.2.513.0': 10}
```

The first OID (`.1.3.6.1.4.1.9839.1.2.532.0`) returns an Opaque value (`\x9fx\x04AÌ¶F`) and I don't know how I can convert it to a float value. I should add that, that is a temperature value of `25.5°C`.

---

In other words, how can I reach the following values by each other?

- `25.5`
- `encoding iso-8859-1, payload [0x9f780441ccb646]`
- `'\x9fx\x04AÌ¶F'`

Comment: You need the original MIB documents to learn what kind of data format is used for this specific OID.

Comment: @LexLi, I know about that, that is opaque. But the problem is I cannot convert opaque to number.

Answer (score 1):

Your value `0x9f780441ccb646` can be

- split into two floats, of which one is `25.589001`, the other part is something else, or
- the middle is the representation of the `pysnmp` object (`__repr__`) without a known interpretation (probably MIB missing), or
- converted to a byte representation (with iso-8859-1 encoding) which is your string `'\x9fx\x04AÌ¶F'`.

So the data is there, it just needs to be extracted from the SNMP packet. The proper way would be to give the corresponding MIB entry to pysnmp.

Alternatively (answering your second question), the manual way of decoding the bytes can be done with the Python's [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module.

```py
import struct

data = 0x9f780441ccb646         # this is what you got from pysnmp
thebytes = struct.pack("l", data)
print(thebytes.decode('latin1'))
print(thebytes)
print(struct.unpack("ff", thebytes))
```

gives

```
F¶ÌAx
b'F\xb6\xccA\x04x\x9f\x00'
(25.589000701904297, 1.4644897383138518e-38)
```

instead of unpacking to two floats, the MIB will tell you how the other data should be interpreted, so instead of `unpack("ff",…` you might want something else, check out the available [format specifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters), for example `"fhh"` would give `(25.589000701904297, 30724, 159)`.

EDIT:

TL;DR:

```
data = '\0\x9fx\x04AÌ¶F'
print("temperature: %f°C" % struct.unpack('>ff', data.encode('latin1'))[1])
```

```
temperature: 25.589001°C
```

To elaborate on the string representation: The bytes you see `'AÌ¶F'` are in a reversed order than the ones in my print statement `'F¶ÌA'` because of the different [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). The byte order is already corrected in the `int`-converted data `0x9f780441ccb646` that you give in your output and I used in the conversion example. If you want to start from the encoded string, you first need to convert it back to the correct memory representation:

```
data = '\0\x9fx\x04AÌ¶F'       # (initial '\0' is for filling the 8-bytes in correct alignment)
thebytes =  data.encode('latin1')
```

But that's only half of the trick, because now the endianess is still wrong. Fortunately `struct` has the flags to correct for that. You can unpack in both byte-orders and choose the right one

```
print("unpacked little-endian: ", struct.unpack("<ff", thebytes))
print("unpacked big-endian:    ", struct.unpack(">ff", thebytes))
unknown, temperature = struct.unpack(">ff", thebytes)
print("temperature: %f°C" % temperature)
```

giving

```
unpacked little-endian:  (2.9225269119838333e-36, 23398.126953125)
unpacked big-endian:     (1.4644897383138518e-38, 25.589000701904297)
temperature: 25.589001°C
```

The correct endianess of the opaque packet is either part of SNMP standard (then probably "network-byte order" [`'!'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) is the correct one), or should also be given in the MIB together with the correct field types which need to be given as format specifiers. If your packets are always 7-byte long, you might try a combination that adds to 7 bytes instead of 8 (`ff` = 4+4), then you can also omit adding the `\0` padding byte.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, my ultimate question is how I can reach `25.58` through the obtained data (`\x9fx\x04AÌ¶F`) which has got by SNMP?

Comment: I edited the answer to also start from the different representation (same data). Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: happy to hear. would you then accept the answer?

Comment: Actually, I'm waiting for other answers as well. Because I guess there are some other solutions using `from pysnmp.proto.rfc1902 import *` or `from pyasn1.codec.ber import decoder, encoder` libraries.

Comment: I understand and agree, the proper decoding by pysnmp itself would be preferable to this bit-hacking solution.  Maybe the knowledge of having a float value at the beginning/end of the data can be modeled into an MIB entry for that OID. Basically that would de-opaque the type and you could read the data with the usual methods.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [TerhorstD's asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67664605/3702377) plus some changes and knowing that the `Opaque` frame consists of `7` bytes in which the `3` bytes of those are constant (`\x9fx\x04` or `159\120\4` in decimal), I wrote the following code snippet to deal with that problem:

```py
...

handler = get("192.168.100.112", [".1.3.6.1.4.1.9839.1.2.532.0",
                                  '.1.3.6.1.4.1.9839.1.2.513.0'],
              hlapi.CommunityData('public'))

for key, value in handler.items():
    try:
        if len(value) == 7 and value[0].encode('latin1')[0] == 159\
                and value[1].encode('latin1')[0] == 120\
                and value[2].encode('latin1')[0] == 4:

            data = value[3:]
            print(struct.unpack('>f', data.encode('latin1'))[0])
        else:
            print(value)
    except AttributeError:
        print(value)
```

Out:

```
25.589001
10
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- Opaque is a little-endian format (`>` in `struct`).

---

[UPDATE]:

More wisely:

```py
for key, value in handler.items():
    try:
        unpacked = struct.unpack('>BBBf', value.encode('latin1'))
        if unpacked[:3] == (159,120,4):
            '''Checking if data Opaque or not.'''

            print(unpacked[-1])
        else:
            print(value)
    except AttributeError:
        print(value)
```

Comment: You do not need to break the raw data, that's exactly what `struct` is for. Depending on how the data comes in it should be either `'>fBBB'` or `'>BBBf'` (both 7 byte) and giving you something like (25.589, 4, 120, 159) or (159, 120, 4, 25.589) or similar. Then you might not need this long if statement and instead can use more python power like `if unpackeddata[:3] == (159,120,4):`

Comment: @TerhorstD Thanks for mentioning. I updated my answer.

Comment: No problem. Happy that it works. Now it's exactly what I wrote in my answer "`print("temperature: %f°C" % struct.unpack('>ff', data.encode('latin1'))[1])` […] If your packets are always 7-byte long, you might try a combination that adds to 7 bytes instead". -> `>BBBf`. – should I update my answer accordingly?

Comment: While reviewing the relevant questions, I think I will still suggest contacting CAREL to get the actual MIB document for this device. Unlike other device vendors who make MIB documents publicly available, CAREL asks its end users to go through technical support. Once you have the document at hand, it should be super clear how the data format was defined for `.1.3.6.1.4.1.9839.1.2.532.0`. No, it won't be `OPAQUE` when you load the proper MIB documents. For example, `DateAndTime` is a similar case.